# How to change the color of a formfield its value has been modified by the user?

Tags: java, colors, itext, form-fields

I have to generate a Pdf file with Itext, and make it editable by the user. Thanks to Itext, that's almost OK. There is a problem, still. How can I show a field has been modified by the user, that is to say, how can I show that the value of a field in the final Pdf is not the one that had been preset ? I was thinking, for instance, of boldening the font, or changing the field's background, but I don't know how to do.

I tried with pdfAction.createJavaScript, but it seems that I can't change the style of an element of my Pdf, because there's no css in it. Can anyone help please ?

Here is a piece of my code :

```
PdfTextFormField champTempsMinutes = PdfTextFormField.createMultilineText(
        pdfDocument,
        new Rectangle(currentX, currentY, 20f, 14f),
        "champTempsMinutes",
        "_ _");

champTempsMinutes.setFontAndSize(fontHelvetica, 8);
champTempsMinutes.setJustification(1);
champTempsMinutes.setFieldName("toto");
                            
champTempsMinutes.setAdditionalAction(
        com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfName.V,
        PdfAction.createJavaScript("app.alert(\"Mouse Enter\")"));
        PdfAction.createJavaScript("app.alert(this.getField('toto').value);"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following additional action which will make the border around your form field red:

```
field.setAdditionalAction(PdfName.V,
                PdfAction.createJavaScript("this.getField('fName').strokeColor = color.red;")
```

Please note that it will only work in the viewers that support JS. Adobe Reader/Acrobat and Foxit are among them.